# Can I run monero desktop wallet over Tor?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, security, privacy, tor

Can I use desktop version of monero wallet https://getmonero.org/downloads/ over Tor ?
I read Web version mymonero.com is rejecting Tor connections. Does desktop wallet work over Tor ?

Answer (score 3):

There are detailed instructions for using Monero over TOR on the project homepage: https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor.

Essentially to use the GUI wallet over TOR, you'd need to have a daemon running on TOR also. Then use `torsocks` when connecting to the daemon.